# value of simply-expanded variable via computed name is different in recipe vs outside recipe

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to figure out if the following behavior is a bug in Make, or intentionally part of the design (if so, I can't find it documented anywhere).  It occurs with both old and new versions of GNU Make that I've tried.

In a nutshell, the behavior is that evaluation of computed-name variables in recipes occurs at the point of invocation of the recipe, and not the place in the file where the recipe is defined, even when the variable is simply-expanded (":=", as opposed to recursively-expanded "=") (not that I would expect that to matter).

Repro code:

---

```
a_name := alpha
b_name := beta

AB := a

target1 : $($(AB)_name)
        echo $^
        echo $($(AB)_name)

alpha : ;

beta : ;

AB := b

target2 : target1 ;
```

---

after invoking `make target2`

output I expect:

> alpha
> alpha

actual output:

> alpha
> beta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read [3.7 How make Reads a Makefile](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reading-Makefiles.html) to understand what you are seeing.

Having read it, you will recognize that the key portion is:

```
Rule Definition

A rule is always expanded the same way, regardless of the form:

immediate : immediate ; deferred
        deferred
```

In that light you see that:

```
target1 : $($(AB)_name)
```

in your makefile is *immediately* expanded, when it is read in phase 1.
At that point the definition of of `AB` is `a`, so `$($(AB)_name)` expands
to `$(a_name)`, and then to `alpha`.

This `alpha` is then, once and for all, the prerequisite to which `$^` will
expand, deferred, in phase 2, in the recipe, So:

```
echo $^
```

in the recipe will echo `alpha`.

The next line in the recipe:

```
echo $($(AB)_name)
```

is also expanded deferred, in phase 2, after the the whole makefile
has been read. At that point `AB` possesses its *final* definition from
phase 1, which was `b`, so here `$($(AB)_name)` expands to `$(b_name)`,
and then to `beta`. So this line of the recipe echoes `beta`.

Comment: Thanks!

So, if I'm understanding you correctly, my hypothesis was wrong:

It is *not* that computed-variables expanded in recipes are computed at the point of invocation of the recipe.

What really happens is: all variables in recipes take the value they have at the end of the makefile, regardless of where the recipe is located.

I look at makefiles differently now!